# MVC4 DisplayModes inconsistency

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm encountering a very odd situation with DisplayModes on ASP.NET MVC4 Beta only intermittently working against my phone. I have a HTC Desire with a User Agent of

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1-update1; de-de; HTC Desire 1.19.161.5 Build/ERE27) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17
```

When I had VS2010 SP1 installed and using a fresh MVC4 application, my Desire was never picked up as a mobile, but iPhone and several others worked fine, IsMobileDevice was always false. I uploaded to Azure and predictably my phone was still not detected as a mobile.

As soon as I installed VS2012, but still using VS2010, my Desire started being picked up as a mobile. The User Agent is exactly the same, but now IsMobileDevice is True. However, when I uploaded to Azure it is still not detected as a mobile.

Throughout all this, there are no errors, just the above behavior. I have experienced exactly the same issue on 2 machines now with multiple different projects. In all cases, the user agent is being detected correctly, it is just the value of IsMobileDevice which changes.

I have tried deploying to Azure with just the MVC4 assemblies in bin deployable assemblies, and I have also tried bootstrapping the .net 4.5 installer on the package but this has made no difference.

I know that I can override the DisplayMode to hack a fix, but this doesn't help me if I want to use the MVC ViewSwitcher and doesn't really solve the problem.

Some help would be greatly appreciated as I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file named ***.mobile.cshtml? This is required if you want MVC to automatically render a different view for a mobile browser. Please try to follow the instructions on http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-website/ to for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Yes I do. On my local machine, using the specified user agent, I receive the mobile page correctly and IsMobileDevice is True as it should be. It is only once I uploaded to Azure that it identifies the same user agent as not a mobile device, meaning it sends the wrong page. Visiting the site using an iPhone user agent provides the correct page.